# Desired effect of value-discarded comparision of GCC anonymous function variables' addresses

Tags: c

The Linux kernel defines a number of helper macros for type neutral numeric operations. Namely the macros `min` and `max` are defined as (in [`include/linux/kernel.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/include/linux/kernel.h#L33))

```
#ifndef max
#define max(x, y) ({ \
        typeof(x) _max1 = (x); \
        typeof(y) _max2 = (y); \
        (void) (&_max1 == &_max2); \
        _max1 > _max2 ? _max1 : _max2; })
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(x, y) ({ \
        typeof(x) _min1 = (x); \
        typeof(y) _min2 = (y); \
        (void) (&_min1 == &_min2); \
        _min1 < _min2 ? _min1 : _min2; })
#endif
```

When expanded they produce anonymous functions that perform the operation type neutral and in-expression-assigment safe way (using GCC anonymous functions). So far so good. What surprised me is the second to last expression produced by these macros:

```
   (void) (&_min1 == &_min2);
```

The addresses of the temporary variables defined within the scope of the anonymous function are compared and the result then discarded; the `(void)` cast preventing any warnings to show up.

I wonder what the desired side effect of this is? Naively I'd expect this to get optimized away, since it has no side effects (at least none I am aware of).

Comment: taking address usually forces values to be dumped to memory. You cannot take address of the register variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will complain for the `==` if both variables don't have the same type. So I suspect this is to ensure the values really can be compared.

Try:

```
int i;
char *p;
(void)min(i, p);
```

And yes, the operation will be optimised away with any optimisation level other than `-O0`.

Comment: Oh! Of course. :) – OTOH: I wonder how much sense this makes? For example I see no problem comparing a, say, `signed long` with a `signed char`, as per the integer promotion rules the operation promotes the `signed char` to `signed long`. And I can think of a lot of cases where one might want to perform a comparison like that.

Comment: @datenwolf: Problem is, you have all or nothing here. Without that you can also compare e.g.`int` and pointers because of conversion rules. Maybe this was more necessary with older compilers (pre-C99) which were much less trigger-happy (and had much less options to request warnings, too). If you want to compare compatible types, you still can cast an argument, even with `typeof()`.

Comment: @machine_1: Do not change correct syntax.